# Can an integral be certifiably non-elementary?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

If you want to convince somebody that a particular natural number is prime, you can hand them a [primality certificate](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrattCertificate.html)--a small bundle of data which can be used to efficiently generate a proof of primality. Does anything similar exist for elementary functions with no elementary antiderivative? Do theorems exist in differential Galois theory (or other fields) which allow us to construct "non-integrability certificates" for, say, $e^{x^2}$ or $\log(\sin x)$?

Comment: I don't know how helpful it is, but I found this: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/elemint.pdf

Comment: Do [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) not meet these criteria ?